# How to put DIV scrollbar inside fixed width DIV (overflow:auto, float:left)

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I have a DIV like below. My problem is, whenever scrollbar is visible, it is displayed outside 300px width. But I need fixed 300px width for DIV irrespective of scrollbar. How can I do that?

```
<div style="width:300px; overflow:auto; float:left;"></div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either place the div in a 300px container and apply the overflow to the inner div.  That should constrain it to the dimensions you are wanting. If that is not desirable, you could experiment with it and see if applying `box-sizing:border-box`, but that is not supported by older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am understanding the question properly with this answer, if not please indicate.

http://jsfiddle.net/hmCFh/1/

HTML

```
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula vulputate, velit sapien suspendisse, ipsum nunc, integer velit aptent non quam. Erat sit consequat lectus, velit risus taciti, in sed, risus tincidunt. Egestas lacus vel voluptatem in volutpat. Sapien lacus suspendisse nec velit. Integer molestie erat, erat lectus luctus ipsum. Nulla massa netus. Odio nunc maecenas modi tortor cras in. Quis nonummy ridiculus vel sed, luctus nulla lectus bibendum justo donec.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula vulputate, velit sapien suspendisse, ipsum nunc, integer velit aptent non quam. Erat sit consequat lectus, velit risus taciti, in sed, risus tincidunt. Egestas lacus vel voluptatem in volutpat. Sapien lacus suspendisse nec velit. Integer molestie erat, erat lectus luctus ipsum. Nulla massa netus. Odio nunc maecenas modi tortor cras in. Quis nonummy ridiculus vel sed, luctus nulla lectus bibendum justo donec.    

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula vulputate, velit sapien suspendisse, ipsum nunc, integer velit aptent non quam. Erat sit consequat lectus, velit risus taciti, in sed, risus tincidunt. Egestas lacus vel voluptatem in volutpat. Sapien lacus suspendisse nec velit. Integer molestie erat, erat lectus luctus ipsum. Nulla massa netus. Odio nunc maecenas modi tortor cras in. Quis nonummy ridiculus vel sed, luctus nulla lectus bibendum justo donec.        
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width:300px; 
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    float:left;
    background:orange;    
}
```

Comment: I am confused what is the change in your code? I also put similar one but its shows scrollbar outside !

Answer (score 0):

You could use `overflow-y: scroll` so that the scrollbar will always be visible and then set the width of the div to `284px` to account for the approx. width of the scrollbar.